# Case-insensitive user-names in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, case-insensitive

By default, Symfony2 matches usernames case-sensitively. I want users to be able to enter *johnsmith*, *JohnSmith*, *johnSMITH*, or any variant of that, and have them all register as *johnsmith*. How do I do this?

I though the easiest way would be to always convert each username to lower-case before comparing them. This is easy to do on the one side (just throw a `lower()` into the SQL statement), but how do I do that for what the user types in in the login form? Since Symfony automatically takes care of the `login_check` route handling, I can't figure it out.

Better yet, is there some option I can set to enable case-insensitivity instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. All I had to do was add another `lower()` around the `where` clause in my SQL statement. Like this:

```
select lower(USERNAME) as USERNAME, PASSWORD, ROLES, ALL_CUSTOMER_ACCESS
from COMPANYNAME_USERS
where lower(USERNAME) = lower(:username)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write correct loadUserByUsername function in UserRepository.
It must not be case sensitive:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('LOWER(u.email) = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', strtolower($username))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if ($user){
       return $user;
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Unable to find user "' . $username . '"');
}
```

Comment: Note that I was not using Doctrine entities or whatnot, that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You already fixed it, but I will explain another solution for users with similar problems:

1. You have to implement your own Provider this way: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider
2. Use the following query instead in method `loadUserByUsername`:

   `$user = $this->findOneBy(array('username' => strtolower($username)));`

This worked for me. (Also in Doctrine Mongo ODM)

Answer (score 0):

In your `setUsername` you could just have the text changed to lowercase like..

```
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = mb_strtolower($username);

    return $this;
}
```

For reference, FOSUserBundle handles this by "canonicalizing" the username (to `usernameCanonical`) and email address (to `canonicalEmail`) in the `updateUser` call (see [Doctrine\UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php#L87-L102) that calls the [Canonicalizer](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/Canonicalizer.php)) which it then uses for searches.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. That will make it so that usernames are always lower-case--which they are anyway (users do not create their usernames; they are created by the company support person). And I am not using that bundle.

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude, really. I don't mean to be.

Comment: It's not a problem. I clearly didn't read the whole question. What DB are you using? As far as I know MySQL searches are case-insensitive, although that wouldn't matter to you if you were using something else.

Comment: I am using Oracle. Though in any case, it is easy enough to always retrieve the lower-cased version using `lower(USERNAME)`. It's what the user types in that I can't figure out how to access.

Comment: If you are using the `entity` security provider you could [Use a Custom Query to Load the User](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user) and lower the case of the username in that before running the query.

Comment: I am not using the `entity` security provider. I am not using an Object Relational Mapper of any sort. I am using raw SQL (we have to build this on top of several existing poorly-designed databases with hundreds of tables each, plus simultaneously fetch and process thousands of records, something not possible with an ORM--so we decided to stick to using raw SQL). In my `UserProvider` I have already done exactly that. It's the **user input** at the login screen that I can't figure out how to lower the case of.

Comment: Just had a head-smack moment... all I needed to do was put a second `lower()` around the relevant part of the `where` clause.

Comment: Glad to have almost helped. :D

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to convert the input into lowercase using CSS ? There are actually ways to control data input before it is handed to the login_check controller, but if you want a quick fix :

```
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```