# Make Doctrine's UniqueEntity constraint case-insensitive

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is there a way to configure [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to treat `foo` and `Foo` as duplicates?

Use case: I have `@UniqueEntity("email")` on my user entity, since I'm using the email address as username. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808332/1668200 the local part of an email address is case-sensitive in theory, but case-insensitive in practice.

I could certainly convert it to lowercase in `setEmail()` (as suggested at 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663365/1668200). Drawbacks:

- Might confuse users (since their email address gets "modified")
- As a comment of the above answer says:

  > That's not a good idea, since there is a small chance it will not get delivered.

So I'd rather reject the user `Foo@example.com`'s registration (if `foo@example.com` is already present), than convert *all* users' addresses to lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html):

> repositoryMethod type: string default: findBy()
>
> The name of the repository method to use for making the query to
>   determine the uniqueness. If it's left blank, the findBy() method will
>   be used. This method should return a countable result.

You could create a function in the repository to find if that email exists applying UPPER() in the sql.